# Avoid Bootstrap menu truncation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap menu that works fine, with one exception:

```
<li class="dropdown" style="display:inline;float:right;width:160px;">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="dropdown" class="modal-close"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> 
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="list-style: none;">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="deleteMe()">Remove Element</a></li>
         <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Add Element</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addDashElem(101)">Chart</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addDashElem(104)">Table</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addDashElem(102)">Gauge</a>
            </li>
                  <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addDashElem(103)">Flag</a>
            </li>
                  <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="addDashElem(103)">Light</a>
            </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

The exception is that the submenu is displayed to the right even when there's no space to be displayed, for example when the menu is close to the end of the screen and it gets truncated.

This is what is displayed, the popup should open to the left side and not to the right:

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pull-left, like so:

```
 <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu pull-left">
```